# Wireless not working on HP pavilion dm5

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, hp-pavilion

I have tried to help my friend out with his wireless problems
he is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but the regular bcma wireless driver isn't working. He has to be about a foot away from the Access point in order to get internet.

He can not install the Broadcom STA wireless driver via jockey and can not find it in the repositories? I know my computer shows it in the repositories.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install **synaptic** form the Ubuntu Software Center

In Synaptic select **bcmwl-kernel-source** and **bcmwl-sta-source**

Then **install** it.

I'm sorry you must have a connection internet try wired.

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain how the instructions you gave will resolve the OPs issue.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10, the package names have changed:

sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source bcmwl-kernel-source